# stopword removal in F#

Tags: f#, f#-scripting

I am trying to write a code to remove stopwords like "the", "this" in a string list etc.

I wrote this code:

```
let rec public stopword (a : string list, b :string list) =

    match [a.Head] with
        |["the"]|["this"] -> stopword (a.Tail, b)
        |[] -> b
        |_ ->  stopword (a.Tail, b@[a.Head])
```

I ran this in the interactive:

```
stopword (["this";"is";"the"], []);;
```

I got this error:

`This expression was expected to have type string list but here has type 'a * 'b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match expressions in F# are very powerful, although the syntax is confusing at first

You need to match the list like so:

```
let rec stopword a =
    match a with
    |"the"::t |"this"::t -> stopword t
    |h::t ->h::(stopword t)
    |[] -> []
```

Comment: Thanks a million!!!!!! This one's so efficient. I wish I can write this code in a few months :)

Answer (score 2):

The actual error is due to the function expecting a tuple argument. You would have to call the function with:

```
let result = stopword (["this";"is";"the"], [])
```

**Edit: since the original question was changed, the above answer is not valid anymore; the logical error in the actual function is that you end up with a single element list of which the tail is taken, resulting in an empty list. On the next recursive call the function chokes on trying to get the head of this empty list**

The function in itself is not correctly implemented though and much more complicated than necessary.

```
let isNoStopword (word:string) =
    match word with
    | "the"|"this" -> false
    | _ -> true

let removeStopword (a : string list) =
    a |> List.filter(isNoStopword)

let test = removeStopword ["this";"is";"the"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation. I tried your suggesstion with my code. It gives this error:  This expression was expected to have type
    string list    
but here has type
    'a * 'b

Comment: @SiddharthaChatterjee - somewhere you have inserted a comma by mistake

Comment: @SiddharthaChatterjee I changed the function to only take one list as an argument instead of the tuple containing two lists (like John Palmer). The two code blocks are independent of each other. The first is how you should call your function, the second is my solution, including the result in the "test" variable.

Comment: Note: John Palmer's solution is the proper implementation of how you tried to solve the problem, while I intended to show that in F# you don't need a recursive function for this particular problem.

Comment: @Dirk I did understand that but your suggestion to run my code didn;t work. im trying to learn F# so was trying to figure out where I made the syntactical/logical mistake apart from offcourse the complexity of the code.

Comment: I would implement isNoStopword using a list of words to create either an F# Set or a .NET HashSet. If your real list of stop words is long that two words this would give you better performance as the test for set member ship will be fast. It would also open the way to loading your stop words from a text file rather than having them in the code.

Comment: you're absolutely right and that's why I put it in a seperate function in the first place, but I wanted to make it simple and similar to the code in the question

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the explaination. I thought the head of an empty list is an empty list. maybe a feature for Microsoft to add?

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned the power of pattern matching in this case. In practice, you usually have a set of stopwords you want to remove. And the `when` guard allows us to pattern match quite naturally:

```
let rec removeStopwords (stopwords: Set<string>) = function
    | x::xs when Set.contains x stopwords -> removeStopwords stopwords xs 
    | x::xs -> x::(removeStopwords stopwords xs)
    | [] -> []
```

The problem with this function and @John's answer is that they are not tail-recursive. They run out of stack on a long list consisting of a few stopwords. It's a good idea to use high-order functions in [List module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx) which are tail-recursive:

```
let removeStopwords (stopwords: Set<string>) xs =
    xs |> List.filter (stopwords.Contains >> not)
```

Comment: thank you for exposing the when guard for this problem. its great to hear various approach's to solve the problem.